# Rails 5 in production with heroku

Tags: heroku, websocket, puma, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I use rails 5 with actioncable on heroku and i have this error only in production

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://adham-chatty.heroku.com/cable' failed: WebSocket opening handshake was canceled
```

i think because of puma

```
2016-01-21T23:33:56.372977+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -t 5:5 -p ${PORT:-3000} -e ${RACK_ENV:-development}`
2016-01-21T23:33:57.651242+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2016-01-21T23:33:58.721808+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] - Gracefully shutting down workers...
2016-01-21T23:33:58.873303+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] === puma shutdown: 2016-01-21 23:33:58 +0000 ===
2016-01-21T23:33:58.873305+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] - Goodbye!
2016-01-21T23:33:58.910391+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] Puma starting in cluster mode...
2016-01-21T23:33:58.910405+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Version 2.15.3 (ruby 2.2.3-p173), codename: Autumn Arbor Airbrush
2016-01-21T23:33:58.910407+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2016-01-21T23:33:58.910409+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Environment: production
2016-01-21T23:33:58.910429+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Process workers: 2
2016-01-21T23:33:58.910453+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Preloading application
2016-01-21T23:33:59.632680+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
```

Comment: Can you show us your puma configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

I just spent an evening and got my rails 5 ActionCable app working wonderfully on Heroku.  I wrote up what I learned after going through a lot of hoops here: http://www.whodya.com/posts/19632.  What I'd guess from looking at your error message above is, ahem, exactly the same problem I had for a bit.  You're trying to use wss: to connect, but this only works if you're using SSL/HTTPS on your server.  Try ws: instead, until you get HTTPS up and running.  Again, my write-up is here (http://www.whodya.com/posts/19632), with my config/settings/etc.

-John

Comment: Your links return "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

Comment: Fixed.  Apologies,  I had just refactored that page and forgot to run my tests for unlogged in users.  <embarrassed/>